# When a UIView does not have a superview when loaded in iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiview

From developer [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW11):

> - (void)sizeToFit
>
> Call this method when you want to resize the current view so that it
> uses the most appropriate amount of space. Specific UIKit views resize
> themselves according to their own internal needs. In some cases, if a
> view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen
> bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent
> view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method.

Is there a case when a view does not have a superview? What are those cases?

Answer (score 0):

a view doesnt have a superview when the view is the **rootview** meaing that there's no other view behind it (besides the window possibly)

OR when it was never added to a view obviously :D

Answer (score -1):

If it is your View Controller's view, it doesn't have a superview.

Comment: You're right. I checked it only in `viewDidLoad`, where it was `nil`. My bad